# Extracting NDVI for Landcover Classes in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, land-cover, image-classification, reducers

I am working on a project where I have created a supervised classification of an image which contains four land cover classes. I have reduced the classification to a frequency histogram that displays the percent land cover taken up by the image, however, I now want to get the NDVI mean for each land cover class.

Using a reducer seems to be the most likely approach but I am not sure how to reduce and match NDVI values associated with each class in this case. The frequency histogram reduction yields the resulting pixel counts:

```
...
classification: Object (4 properties)
0: 15330.674509803957
1: 7207.431372549016
2: 71314.45098039194
3: 3969.709803921568
```

Ideally, I would get an object that looks like this:

```
classification: Object (4 properties)
0: {pixel_count: 15330.674509803957, NDVI: ...}
1: {pixel_count: 7207.431372549016, NDVI: ...}
2: {pixel_count: 71314.45098039194, NDVI: ...}
3: {pixel_count: 3969.709803921568, NDVI: ...}
```

How could I go about computing this reduction?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still interested to know if there is a simple reduction method that could do this, however, I did find a workaround.

I used my land cover classification band to create a mask and computed the NDVI for the image for a series of different masks to limit the land cover type for which I was calculating the NDVI value for.